# PhoneGap 2.1.0 - window.RequestFileSystem

Tags: ipad, cordova, filesystems, ios6, xcode4.5

I have updated to iOS6, and due to this have been trying to update to PhoneGap version 2.1.0. (As the camera etc. does not seem to work in versions previous to this - I have now got this part working) However when I try to access the filesystem by running the following line of code:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,  success, fail);
```

The app just crashes out, with no error etc. If I put this line on the main page and start from within the simulator then I receive the following error:

```
2012-09-25 11:26:38.741 MobileManager[4866:15b03] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2012-09-25 11:26:59.756 MobileManager[4866:17f03] void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation     *): delegate (webView:runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:initiatedByFrame:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
2012-09-25 11:26:59.766 MobileManager[4866:15b03] -[NSNull intValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x275678
2012-09-25 11:26:59.767 MobileManager[4866:15b03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull intValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x275678'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x144012 0x257de7e 0x1cf4bd 0x133bbc 0x13394e 0xd953 0x60812 0x5ff9e 0x60379 0x25916b0     0x1119035 0xc7f3f 0xc796f 0xea734 0xe9f44 0xe9e1b 0x33ae7e3 0x33ae668 0x37f65c 0x22b6 0x21e5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

What does this error mean, and how can I resolve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had accidentally set the LocalFileSystem variable to something else (LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT was undefined.